# Chrome Extension JavaScript Functionality

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Following is the code I tried to find a word on a webpage. However, I am unable to get the desired functionality. When the extension icon in the browser is clicked, the alert message comes up with "Not Found", when the alert window is closed, the textbox and button appear, when the button is clicked nothing happen.

Desired functionality: User enters text and clicks on the button, then if the word is not found the alert message should come up.

Need suggestions to get it working. Thanks

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Word Finder</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #status {
white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 600px;
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="status">
  <input class="word" type="text"></input>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**content.js**

```
var n = 0;
function findInPage(str) {
console.log("We are here");

var txt, i, found;
if (str == "") {
    return false;
}
// Find next occurance of the given string on the page, wrap around   to   the
// start of the page if necessary.
if (window.find) {
    // Look for match starting at the current point. If not found, rewind
    // back to the first match.
    if (!window.find(str)) {
        while (window.find(str, false, true)) {
            n++;
        }
    } else {
        n++;
    }
    // If not found in either direction, give message.
    if (n == 0) {
        alert("Not found.");
    }
} else if (window.document.body.createTextRange) {
    txt = window.document.body.createTextRange();
    // Find the nth match from the top of the page.
    found = true;
    i = 0;
    while (found === true && i <= n) {
        found = txt.findText(str);
        if (found) {
            txt.moveStart("character", 1);
            txt.moveEnd("textedit");
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    // If found, mark it and scroll it into view.
    if (found) {
        txt.moveStart("character", -1);
        txt.findText(str);
        txt.select();
        txt.scrollIntoView();
        n++;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, start over at the top of the page and find first match.
        if (n > 0) {
            n = 0;
            findInPage(str);
        }
        // Not found anywhere, give message. else
        alert("Not found.");
    }
}
return false;
}

window.onload=function(){
console.log("On load function");
var bt = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
bt.addEventListerner('click',findInPage());
console.log("After function call");
};
```

Comment: Please read the chrome extensions architecture article: you need a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I have updated the code. Now, here, if I hard code a string, given string if found on the web page is highlighted. However, I am unable to take the string from the textbox in the UI pane of the extension. This could be something I am missing, but I am not sure what it is, at the moment. Maybe, I should use something else other than window.onload!!

Comment: Got it working. Had to reorganize the code in the js files.